# What is correct coding practice while using attributes in C?

Tags: c, syntax, attributes

If we are writing attributes to some variables or function, what is correct practice? I will elaborate my question with the help of following styles.

```
int a __attribute__((aligned(32)));

__attribute__((aligned(32))) int a;

__attribute__((aligned(32)))
int a;

int __attribute__((aligned(32))) a;
```

What do you think is better or correct way of writing attributes?

Comment: On which criterias are we supposed to decide which one is the best ? This is a very subjective question.  
Regardless, if efficiency is the same, I'd choose in every situation `int a;`. If there is any details to add to this declaration, just comment it.

Comment: And whatever way you decide, do it the same way every time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to follow standard C. All of your examples are non-standard.

Since C11, you can use the `_Alignas` keyword in standard C:

```
_Alignas(32) int x;
```

This is the "best" way since it is standard and portable.

Comment: You could include `<stdalign.h>` for a bit of a prettier syntax: `alignas` instead of `_Alignas`

Comment: Yep, that makes the code compatible with C++ `alignas` and `alignof`. Which may or may not be a good thing.